# How might I have a heterogeneous collection in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sti

I'm somewhat new to Rails and coming from Java, so I might be completely off base here, but here's what I want to do:

I have a class A that has a collection of other objects. That collection can contain B, C, and/or D objects. Importantly,

1. B is actually a parent class of a family of classes (probably
   implemented via STI and a JSONB data store for the differences)
2. C and D are composed of one or more B's, but will still respond to
   the same methods as B (i.e. B, C, and D have duck-typed methods).

From an instance of A, I want to be able to call, say, @a.collection[2].do_this and call the appropriate #do_this.

With that in mind, I'm looking at examples online and the closest to what I can see is the classic :polymorphic example with Posts, Videos, etc. sharing a single Comment class. However, that seems like it's the reverse of what I want (many-to-one rather than one-to-many). Am I looking at this backwards or something? Or can I do some sort of foreign-key thing and trick ActiveRecord into doing multitable inheritance? I've skimmed through the Enterprise Rails chapter on MTI, but I'm hoping for an easier/more appropropriate way given the situation.

Comment: I think you described STI and Polymorphic Associations. I do not get the point were these technics do not fit your problem. Furthmore it sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me. You explained what you try to build. Can you please explain why you need that and what you try to achieve - in a less abstract way?

Comment: @spickermann I provided the background information to illustrate what I'd like to do. The meat of the question is, "In Rails, what is the proper way to create a heterogeneous collection without using STI?"

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage MTI in this case and use source for executing method #do_this for this you do want to look in to source and source type methods. I am talking strictly via active record

```
has_many :related_tickers
has_many :catalysts,  through: :related_tickers, source: :companiable, source_type: "Catalyst"
has_many :strategic_initiatives,  through: :related_tickers, source: :companiable, source_type: "StrategicInitiative"
has_many :projects,  through: :related_tickers, source: :companiable, source_type: "Project"
```

Now you can load things via related_tickers and call #do_this method via that model. In ruby if you have implemented same method in each class that should execute as per duck typing dictates if a method can be respond via object that will run. you can use eval and send method as well to ease the load on the programming site. Hope this helps but if not please give me the specific problem so i can produce better solution.

Comment: In your example, what does `companiable` look like?

Comment: companiable will have two fields in table companiable_id and companiable_type where the id represents the record number of type in above example case that can be Project or Catalyst or Strategic Initiative.